# How can I tell Nginx to silently ignore requests that don't match?

Tags: nginx

I have a server block listening to 80 port requests on a specific server name along with some location directives. How can I make nginx treat any request that doesn't match as if it hadn't received it, that is let it time out? Currently those requests are treated with an 404 error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make nginx treat any request that doesnt match as if it hadnt received it, that is let it time out?

You can't unwind the clock. To find out what server name is being requested (from TLS-SNI and/or `Host` header), nginx must first `accept` the connection (which will cause the operating system's TCP/IP stack to send a SYN-ACK packet back to the requestor, in order to advance the TCP handshake). Once the connection has been accepted, the other side knows something is listening. So you've already foregone the opportunity for a connection timeout.

Having irrevocably lost *that* opportunity, the next opportunity you have is to hit the socket receive timeout. Since the client will be waiting for the server to respond with *something*, you could theoretically trigger its receive timeout by not responding at all. There is no mechanism in standard nginx currently to tell it to sit there and do nothing for a while, but if you are willing to involve another piece of software as well, then you could use the `proxy_pass` directive or similar to offload that responsibility to another server. Beware, however, that this will keep some amount of operating system resources in use by your server for the life of the connection. Nginx operates on sockets, not raw packets, and the operating system manages those sockets.

Having answered the question as asked, I think it's better to question the premise of the question. Why do you want the client to time out? If your goal is to mess with or "pay back" a malicious attacker, nginx is the wrong tool. This is the space of computer security and you're going to need to use tools that operate at a lower layer on the networking stack. Nginx is designed to be a webserver, not a honeypot.

If your goal is simply to hide the fact that there's a server listening at all, then your goal is impossible to achieve with the way HTTP works currently. Firewalls are only able to achieve ghosting like that by rejecting the connection *before* it's accepted. Thus, the TCP handshake never proceeds, no SYN-ACK packet gets sent back to the client, and as far as anyone can tell that *entire port* is a black hole. But it's not possible to do this *after* determining what server name has been requested. The IP address and port are available from the very first packet; the server name is not.

Someday in the not-so-distant future, HTTP may use UDP instead of TCP, and the request parameters (such as the server name) may be presented up front on the first packet. Unless and until that becomes the norm, however, the situation I describe above will remain.

Comment: just out of curiosity, would it be theoretically possible in userland? I mean is there an API , at least in unixlike systems that a listening socket can use to inspect the SYN packet before it accepts it?

Comment: @Paralife There are two ways I know of, the first is to use a raw socket: set socket option `SOCK_RAW` and/or protocol `IPPROTO_RAW`, exact combination depending on platform and desired behavior, also usually requires special permission/capability flag. However, you will forgo all kernel management of the TCP state machine, i.e. you have to reimplement TCP yourself (or find a userland library which does it for you).

Comment: The other option is to put the interface in promiscuous mode and sniff/inject with (lib)pcap. Even more work than raw sockets (implement TCP, IP, and ICMP yourself!). Either way, it's better to use tools others have already created (like I alluded to before) than to do this yourself, except if you want to learn how all of this works (and are in a safe/sandboxed environment to play).

Answer (score 8):

There is a way to ignore every request and tell nginx to respond nothing:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  return 444;
}
```

Documented here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

> The non-standard code 444 closes a connection without sending a response header.

Comment: The question is asking for ignore request, not close connection.

Comment: That's true. However, it would be very unwise to leave the connection open. This way, an attacker could simply make requests until the server runs out of resources to open connections.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are trying to deflect malicious requests.  Something like this might work (untested).

Set up a default server (catches any requests that don't match an existing server name), and then redirect the client back to itself:

```
server {
    listen  80 default_server;
    rewrite ^ http://127.0.0.1/;
}
```

You'd have to setup a similar catch-all for invalid locations inside your valid server blocks.  Might be more of a headache than you want.

I don't know how useful this would really be in practice.  Might be better to consider fail2ban or some other tool that can monitor your logs and ban clients at the firewall.

Comment: Yes, for unwanted requests, I want to simulate the situation where my router simply does not forward the port in question, and the request just times out. And I cant do that in the firewall, because requests from the same host:port might be actually wanted. The filtering is done on the whole uri...

Comment: Wouldn't the above-mentioned server block cause an infinite loop?

You rewrite the URL then serve its contents, but fetching the rewritten contents will cause nginx to evaluate the rewrite again to rewrite "http://127.0.0.1/" to itself in an infinite loop. Sounds like a recipe for unexpected/crashy behavior.